# Calling an API from a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

Hello All: I am hoping someone can help me with this.  I have never done a call to an API and am really out of my depth.  What I am trying to do is a call to an API on a wordpress page.  Here is what I have from the API:
http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest//distance.///

I have an API key.  I have been trying to learn how to do this but there are thousands of ways and am really at a loss how to do this on a wordpress page.  Can anyone help?

Thanks so much,  Gerard

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in php (here I use [file_get_contents](http://fr.php.net/file_get_contents)):

```
$distance = file_get_contents("http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/<api_key>/distance.<format>/<zip_code1>/<zip_code2>/<units>");
```

Example taken from their [site](http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/API):

```
 http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/qVuOZidNAe5osYgYHbyK33EHpJD2nKjOFODE6QsH5y6yxnxfy5ZC9DjynXBLHUAm/distance.json/1000/2000/km
```

You can also use cURL or anything which can call an external page.

To decode json, have a look on [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php).

Think about caching the values using your database or user cookies if possible to avoid multiple unnecessary requests.

EDIT: Based on the code provided in your comment (I took a fake API key from demonstration purposes):

```
$distance = file_get_contents("http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/qVuOZidNAe5osYgYHbyK33EHpJD2nKjOFODE6QsH5y6yxnxfy5ZC9DjynXBLHUAm/distance.json/48433/485‌​01/miles"); 
print_r(json_decode($distance));
```

Comment: thanks Louis, but still no luck; here is my exact code:   `$distance = file_get_contents("http://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/<cDArCXHunjAwgpZcXjhx6fI2J3dqLaZYNAppx7UUrurHUqTRJbpQq7Taa7BWhAU4>/distance.<format>/<48433>/<48501>/<miles>");

echo $distance;`    but it basically shows nothing on the page; can you see anything that i am doing wrong?

Comment: please use a fake API key (just in case...)

Comment: Hey Louis - i saw your edited answer after i posted my comment; and I think it worked...looking it over now...thanks so much...

Comment: think about accepting my answer if everything is okay for you :)